# Expo eas build is failing consistently for unknown reason

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, expo

I have a react native application that I am trying to build with expo `eas build --platform ios`

It starts building the application and everything is fine until it gets to the last step of the build process and then fails for some reason. I can not figure out why it is failing.

This is the error that I am getting:

```
⚠️  ld: duplicate method '+moduleName' in
┌─[category]: ExpoBridgeModule-42cab667980256920bca399fb283d4e0.o ExpoModulesCore/libExpoModulesCore.a
└─[class]: ExpoBridgeModule-f3e2a238b656aef6ef05761b66817421.o ExpoModulesCore/libExpoModulesCore.a
⚠️  ld: method '+UIDatePickerMode:' in category from /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Rippe-ahqtpmtfssnflkdiarrwiihwmnhk/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Rippe/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/react-native-date-picker/libreact-native-date-picker.a(RNDatePickerManager.o) conflicts with same method from another category
› Generating debug Rippe » Rippe.app.dSYM
› Executing Rippe » Bundle React Native code and images
    the transform cache was reset.

❌  error: File /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Rippe-ahqtpmtfssnflkdiarrwiihwmnhk/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Rippe/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/Rippe.app/main.jsbundle does not exist. This must be a bug with React Native, please report it here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues

    Run script build phase '[CP-User] Generate app.config for prebuilt Constants.manifest' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'EXConstants' from project 'Pods')
▸ ** ARCHIVE FAILED **
▸ The following build commands failed:
▸   PhaseScriptExecution Bundle\ React\ Native\ code\ and\ images /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Rippe-ahqtpmtfssnflkdiarrwiihwmnhk/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Rippe/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Rippe.build/Release-iphoneos/Rippe.build/Script-00DD1BFF1BD5951E006B06BC.sh (in target 'Rippe' from project 'Rippe')
▸ (1 failure)
** ARCHIVE FAILED **
The following build commands failed:
    PhaseScriptExecution Bundle\ React\ Native\ code\ and\ images /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Rippe-ahqtpmtfssnflkdiarrwiihwmnhk/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Rippe/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Rippe.build/Release-iphoneos/Rippe.build/Script-00DD1BFF1BD5951E006B06BC.sh (in target 'Rippe' from project 'Rippe')
(1 failure)
Exit status: 65
+-------------+-------------------------+
|           Build environment           |
+-------------+-------------------------+
| xcode_path  | /Applications/Xcode.app |
| gym_version | 2.211.0                 |
| sdk         | iPhoneOS16.2.sdk        |
+-------------+-------------------------+
Looks like fastlane ran into a build/archive error with your project
It's hard to tell what's causing the error, so we wrote some guides on how
to troubleshoot build and signing issues: https://docs.fastlane.tools/codesigning/getting-started/
Before submitting an issue on GitHub, please follow the guide above and make
sure your project is set up correctly.
fastlane uses `xcodebuild` commands to generate your binary, you can see the
the full commands printed out in yellow in the above log.
Make sure to inspect the output above, as usually you'll find more error information there
[stderr] 
[!] Error building the application - see the log above
Error: The "Run fastlane" step failed with an unknown error. Refer to "Xcode Logs" below for additional, more detailed logs.
```

I removed every reference to `DatePicker`

Can anyone help figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest looking at the imports within your tsx files .  I was able to solve a similar issue by removing an unused "typescript" import .